# Inserting text into a textarea using .load() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

having a bit of a nightmare, I am trying to use jQuery to insert some text taken from a .load() call into a form field (textfield) after a user logs in (basically prefilling some known details). It is #bookName and #bookEmail I am having problems with

The code I am using is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/login.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html) {
            if (html == 1) {
                $("#loginPanel").load("/ajax/login-panel.php");     
                $("#bookName").load("/ajax/getSessionDetails.php #userUsername");
                $("#bookEmail").load("/ajax/getSessionDetails.php #userEmail"); 
                $("#bookingLogin").hide("fast"); 
            } else {
                $("#loginError").html("Sorry, login failed, please try again");
            }
        }
    });
```

If I hardcode such as `$("#bookName").html("Test Content");` it works OK so it must be a problem with the .load call.

I looked around and found some guy suggest something like the following code but I couldn't get it to work:

```
$.get(htmlBannerUrl, function(data){
  $('textarea').val(data);
});
```

Comment: is the url u r passing correct? $("#bookName").load("/ajax/getSessionDetails.php #userUsername");

Comment: Sorry, I missed out some of my question, I am getting data back from the call, the #loginpanel (a div) correctly display, the problem is it is not putting data into #bookname and #bookemail, both of which are textfields: `<input type="text" value="" class="textfield large" id="bookEmail" name="bookEmail">`

Comment: Firebug gives me the following response for getSessionDetails:
`<div id="userEmail>user@domain.com</div><div id="userUsername>bateman_ap</div>`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use text();

```
$('#loginError').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are firing too many simultaneous ajax requests:

```
$("#loginPanel").load("/ajax/login-panel.php");     
$("#bookName").load("/ajax/getSessionDetails.php #userUsername");
$("#bookEmail").load("/ajax/getSessionDetails.php #userEmail");
```

The HTTP 1.1 spec advises clients to only allow 2 simultaneous connections to any originating host. You might try reducing those to a single one within $.ajax's success callback, to see if it works as expected. Also see:

[How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browser)

Comment: The call is getting data back so I don't think thats the problem, rather placing that data in the textfield

Answer (score 0):

Well I had to use a workaround to do this, not nice at all but at least let me stick it to the background until the rest of the build is done.

Instead of adding it as a value I had to build a dupe of the whole form in a new php page and insert it using .load. Good thing is that it works, bad thing is that it isn't that useful if I want to reuse the code, I will have to build another page.

I should keep this question open as I have only found a workaround, is that how Stackoverflow works?