# Coldfusion concurrent ajax post

Tags: ajax, iis, coldfusion, request

I'm creating a script for uploading and processing something.

1. user upload an excel file
2. in the destination script, the excel data are converted to a query
3. the query converted to json using SerializeJSON
4. and then this json data is submitted one by one using ajax and setInterval function

currently the interval for setInverval is set to 500 (milliseconds). so far is safe and doesn't kill the web server.

from Firebugs Console tab, with this interval I saw maximum 2 concurrent ajax request.

is there any limitation on maximum concurrent ajax request when using CF and IIS?

I'm using CF 9 standar edition with IIS in win 2008 server.

Thank you

(sorry, english is not my mother tounge :p)

Answer (score 1):

Why not loop the Excel document and save the lines server side instead of submitting one by one with additional HTTP requests?

As for your question see what follows:

**Maximum Number of Requests**

- The bottleneck is most likely the
  browser. Have a look at this
  question:
  [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browser)
- I don't think IIS limits requests.
- ColdFusion requests limits are set in
  the administrator under Server
  Settings > Request Tuning. By default 10 processing, up to 1000 more queued.