# What the "Channel" mean in facebook chat application?

Tags: facebook

Facebook uses publish/subscribe pattern for their chat app. I used Firebug to catch request in facebook site and I saw that every request to receive message from facebook server almost link to an address with pattern : http://[number].[number].chanel.facebook.com. There is about 0->20 channels which mean number in address pattern will range in [0-20].
I don't know why they need to use channel as subdomain ? Does it relate to divide processing chat message to multiple service (server) to increase server performance ? or just a subdomain name ?
What is your opinion ? I'd like to hear your interesting idea on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they use sub-somains because there's a limit on how many connections per domain a browser can keep open.

See [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browser)

So, those sub-domains are not "channels".

Answer (score 0):

These are special servers which handle only chat messages and notifications. Source: Rodrigo Schmidt's lecture (https://www.facebook.com/rodrigo)