# Sending ajax requests in batch of 3 or 5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am in asp.net mvc paradigm. On one of my views, I have two fields `Start Number` and `End Number`. User is allowed to enter numeric values in these fields and when he clicks on submit button I have to loop from startNumber to endNumber and send an ajax requests for each iteration of the loop.

I have a scenario when the difference between start number and end number may range to 100's, so I am planning to send ajax requests in batch of 3 or 5. e.g I will send three requests and wait for them to complete and after that, I need to send next three until the loop is completed. I don't know how to target this problem.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/q/6986458/114029 and here http://stackoverflow.com/q/4240847/114029

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hammering your server with multiple AJAX request I'd recommend you send a single AJAX request containing all the necessary information. This will be more efficient rather than sending multiple requests with smaller payload.

Comment: Yes, In ordinary circumstances it is desireable to bundle ajax requests but in this case if I send all the necessary data in one or even 2 or 3 requests they might time out or at best user will have to wait more than a minute or two to see the response.

Answer (score 0):

Create batch of 3 or 4 requests, and use below sample code which detect AJAX requests comepletes or not.

```
$( ".log" ).ajaxStop(function() {
  $(this).text( "Triggered ajaxStop handler." );
});
```

After comeleting all request,call another batch.