# Understanding configuration for parallel calling in web app (IIS + MS SQL)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, web-config, iis-7.5, app-config

We have an ASP.NET MVC application + IIS 7.5 + SQL Server 2008 R2.

We have to load a lot of aggregate counters on the each page.
We decided to use ajax and call with javascript
for each counter or groups of counters and return them as *JSON* result.

We solve the problem that user doesn't wait for page loading, page loads fast.
User waits for counters loading while seeing other page content.

But we thought that if we make calls from javascript - our queries will be make **async**, but we notice, that it is not. All our javascipt calls runs immediately, but action that they invoke are in **queue**.

If we use *Async Controller* ability  - all counters calculating simultaneously, but user has to wait for the longest counter calculating before page loads.

**The question:**
We want to understand what is happens if we use *ajax* and call two or more *actions* simultaneously. And how can we configuring this. (also in each action we make some queries to sql server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're hitting the same issue I bumped up against a week or so ago:

> [Why would multiple simultaneous AJAX calls to the same ASP.NET MVC action cause the browser to block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428413/why-would-multiple-simultaneous-ajax-calls-to-the-same-asp-net-mvc-action-cause-t/4434805#4434805)

Comment: Thanks, I see some useful explanations and answers at the link you provided. Also do you know some good explanations about session performance (IIS settings may be, MVC and ModelBinders etc.). Unfortunately, didn't find enough at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx