# AJAX call blocks browser when calling to Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Setup:

Ruby on Rails, Posgresql, Backbone

Situation:

I got a media archive app. The user moves around the site and selects images/movies etc to be packaged in a zip-file for download. Since the zip can get rather large I decided to mail the download link once the compression is done. However, I still have to wait for the request to get done before being able to do anything else. The link below describes the same problem but he is using ASP.NET and I can't find this Session State anywhere in the Rails documentation or on Google. Is it even called Session State in Rails?

[Why would multiple simultaneous AJAX calls to the same ASP.NET MVC action cause the browser to block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428413/why-would-multiple-simultaneous-ajax-calls-to-the-same-asp-net-mvc-action-cause)

Ideas?

Comment: Can't really tell without seeing your code, but it sounds like you're using *synchronous* request (so technically not **a** jax - the **a** is for *async*).

Comment: I am very sure that I use async since that is default in jQuery.