# ASP.NET MVC — calls to controller performs sequentially, not parallel

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

On our site we found that when user awaits for page loading, try of opening another page will stuck until the first one will load.

For imitation we created a test page with a button, click on which performs two simultaneous AJAX calls using XMLHttpRequest. Running it multiple times and analysing the process give us a clue — MVC performs one call after another, but not same time.

I always thought wrong or it's just question of an incorrect configuration?

MVC5 and different versions of IIS.

**Update:** turned testing action into async as show below:

```
public virtual async Task<JsonResult> Test3()
        {
            await Task.Run( () => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000));
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
```

Situation is the same (and looks like T4MVC not works with async actions).

Comment: Tasks are (still) not threads and async is not parallel: https://www.wintellect.com/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel
https://code-maze.com/csharp-delegates/

Comment: You might be affected by [session state's requirement for exclusive access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428413/why-would-multiple-simultaneous-ajax-calls-to-the-same-asp-net-mvc-action-cause).  Also note Darin's comment on using `cache: false` in your AJAX call.

Comment: The same situation it not only on ajax. 
Setting the SessionState to disabled crashed all web application in a such violent way — under SO died NLog, few other things and our security logic, while setting to read-only kinda helps, but needs additional testing.

Comment: Thank thou @sellotape, read-only session state works, so thou can write it as an answer.