# $.get, $.post, $.ajax, $(elm).load to .ashx page problem

Tags: jquery, ashx

HTML page

```
    // in script tag
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = "list.ashx";

        $.get(url + "?get", function (r1) { alert("get: " + r1); });
        $.post(url + "?post", function (r2) { alert("post: " + r2); });
        $.ajax(url + "?ajax", function (r3) { alert("ajax: " + r3); });
        $("div:last").load(url + "?load", function (r4) { alert("load: " + r4); });
    });

    // in body tag
    <div></div>
```

in 'list.ashx'

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) { context.Response.Write("ok"); }
```

the result

- $.get and $.post reach list.ashx but
  no return
- $.ajax not reach list.ashx
- $.load fully success

The problems are

- why only '$.load' work?
- how to make $.get or $.post work?

update

```
        $("input").click(function () {
            $.ajax({ url: url
                , context: this
                , data: "ajax=test"
                , cache: false
                , async: false
                , global: false
                , type:"POST"
                , processData: false
                , dataType: "html"
                , success: function (data) { alert(data); }
                , error: function (data) { alert(data.responseText); }
                });
        });
```

it's always hit error:function(){} but the 'data.responseText' is the correct result!!

Comment: The Firebug "net" tab or Chrome's resource tracker should tell you more about what happens to the requests.

Comment: *"$.ajax not reach list.ashx"* That's because you're calling `ajax` incorrectly: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ But don't worry about it, `get` and `post` are just wrappers for it anyway, you can drop it from your experiment. Out of curiousity, what happens to `$.get(url + "?load", function (r1) { alert("get: " + r1); });`? (Note I've changed the query string.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the reason your `$.ajax()` doesn't work is because it's [syntactically invalid](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  It should look more like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", // or "GET"
    url: "list.ashx",
    data: "postvar=whatever",
    success: function(r3){
       alert("ajax: " + r3);
    }
});
```

Also, when using `$.get` and `$.post`, you should put the data in the second parameter:

```
$.get(url, 'getvar=whatever', function (r1) { alert("get: " + r1); });
$.post(url, 'postvar=whatever', function (r2) { alert("post: " + r2); });

// or use a map

$.get(url, { getvar : 'whatever' }, function (r1) { alert("get: " + r1); });
$.post(url, { postvar : 'whatever' }, function (r2) { alert("post: " + r2); });
```

Comment: +1 This is correct, and explains conclusively why `$.ajax` never returns.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are firing off four asynchronous requests in one go to the same page, this might be relevant:

- [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browser)

Comment: Thanks, i tried invoke them individualy. the result is the same.