# Request ASP.NET handler through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ashx

So I'm trying to teach myself asp.net along with javascript. I downloaded a website template and converted it to an asp site.  It has a contact form which the javascript called a php function to send an email.  I can't use php to send email on my hosting site.

The template included a file `MailHandler.ashx` that I should be able to use to send mail with asp.  I have done my research, and I believe I have this code in working order.  My question is, where the javascript used to call the PHP file, how do I convert that to call this MailHandler file?

This is the relevant code calling my php file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:_.mailHandlerURL,   //this value is the path to the php file
    data:{
        name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
        email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
        phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
        fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
        state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
        message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
        owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
        stripHTML:_.stripHTML
},
```

I understand that this is invoking a post method to the php file, so how do I invoke a post method do my Mailhandler file?

This is my handler file:

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler {
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

             //create mail client, create message, send email

    }
}
```

Comment: Write the url of your handler page in `url` of `$.ajax`. This `_.mailHandlerURL` should be replaced by url of `ashx` page.

Comment: thats all i do?  so the method will work exactly the same going to my handler file?

Comment: This will do a post ajax request to your ashx page. In the `ProcessRequest` function , do your coding to send email.

Comment: ok thanks, That's what i've been trying and its not working. I guess I have issues somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Check this earlier post [$.get, $.post, $.ajax, $(elm).load to .ashx page problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450139/get-post-ajax-elm-load-to-ashx-page-problem) i believe your problem is the formatting - see the data: attribute.

You definitely need to set _.mailHandlerURL to the url of the ashx file.

I believe it should look more like this:

```
var dataParams = "name="+_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form));
    dataParams += ", email="+_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form));
        // etc for the rest 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:_.mailHandlerURL,   //this value is the path to the php file
    data:dataParams
},
```

If this code is exactly as if you need to add a closing bracket after the last } in the java script and add a semi-colon instead of a comma:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:_.mailHandlerURL,   //this value is the path to the php file
    data:dataParams
});
```

Comment: that doesn't work either. I get an error, but it says "undefinederror"

Comment: have updated my answer - you need a closing bracket and a semi colon - remove the last comma.

Comment: Well, I actually have more code after that.  I did finally get an error though..The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section.  Must have something to do with permissions on my folder, or maybe the way my web server has things configured

Comment: An error is at least a starting point - perhaps close this question and open a new one with error dump?

Comment: yeah..i think i can get it figured out now that i at least have errors