# how many parallel requests does the latest version of chrome, FF & IE support

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browser)

how many parallel requests does the latest version of chrome, FF & IE support