# Increase Internet Explorer 7 concurrent http request

Tags: ajax, http-request

I'm working on some performance improvements on a very big AJAX application. One of the constrains is that the applicaiton requires to be performing in internet explorer 7. Problem is that IE7 will not allow more than 2 concurrent HTTP request at the same time. I had tried to modify the registry values for MaxConnectionsPerServer and MaxConnectionsPer1_0Server to 10 in a winxp sp4 virtual machine, but still all the javascripts keeps loading in a serialized way no more than 2 at a time.

Is there any way to trully force IE7 to use 6 or 8 concurrent HTTP requests please? (I know IE8, IE9, FF and many others do this, yes, it's a problem that our customer only wants IE7 and will not upgrade the browser)

Answer (score 0):

No, its a built in feature of the program and not configrable. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browser). My advice would be to refractor your code so only two are sent at a time

Answer (score 0):

Is the limitation 2 concurrent requests to the same domain? One alternative might be to spread your ajax calls across several domains or sub-domains. In this way, the browser will make multiple simulaneous calls, although I'm not sure  if this would introduce some cross site scripting issues.