# How many PENDING ajax requests are allowed in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, xmlhttprequest

First, I want to make clear that I am not talking about this question [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browser) , which is about simultaneous requests.

Instead, I want know if there is a limit on the number of pending ajax requests, before the browser potentially starts cancelling them or throwing errors.

Running some simple tests, I've seen that when the limit of about 6 simultaneous requests is hit, the browser will start queuing requests in a graceful manner. Once a 'slot' becomes available, it is used and a new request is sent to the server.

I have also seen that Chrome, Firefox and even IE will gracefully handle a queue of about 100 requests.

Comment: as you're already testing aren't you the best person to answer this question?

Comment: I would guess that memory is the only limitation. I don't think there is much of a resource impact of queued requests. I guess testing-to-destruction will be the only way to know for sure.

Comment: This :
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browser

Comment: As per firefox 3.6.18 config , the `network.http.max-connections` is 30 ,`network.http.max-connections-per-server` is 15,`network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server` is 6,`network.http.pipelining.maxrequests` is 4 . From this can you find something??? I'm not sure what this is about!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your distinction between 'simultaneous' requests and 'pending' requests..if a request hasn't completed, then it is open, and hence by definition is 'simultaneous' with any requests open at the same time. If I did misunderstand something could you clarify please?

Comment: @boycy according to the OP's post, the browsers make 6 simultaneous requests before queuing them.  The # of queued/pending requests seems to be the question

Answer (score 2):

I also guess that it's indicated from maximum number of current opened connection and here's the situation in IE [Max-Connections](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/07/21/internet-explorer-8-and-maximum-concurrent-connections.aspx)
and this thread also may help [How many concurrent AJAX requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browser)