# muliple XHR requests at the same time

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a basic question about asynchronous request call.
Does the browser execute more than one XHR at the same time, or does it abort a request if a new one is send, while the first is still working? Are there differences in the implementation between browsers?

I tried to create a hole bunch of requests in a loop, but all, except the last one, were aborted. So for now i plan to implement a queue for all requests, but i am not certain if this is really needed.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, browsers do allow [multiple concurrent XHR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browser).

If your code only succeeds with *one*, it's most probably because of a bug. If possible, create a small example and show us what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found my fault! The wrapping class for my request was coded badly, and creating new Objects of my request Class did not result in the creating of new XmlHttpRequest Objects. Every creation of a Request Object called the open() method on the same XmlHttpRequest Object. That is what leaded into the abort.