# Get number of concurrent requests by browser

Tags: performance, browser

I'm trying to figure out whether it would be worthwhile to spread image requests across multiple sub-domains. [This article](link broken) for example says:

> **Most** browsers can only make two requests at a time, so the browser will request two files, download them and then move on to the next two. The more HTTP requests, or separate components a page requires to display properly, the longer the user will have to wait.

When they say **most**, which browsers in particular? Is that number related to the number of concurrent XMLHttpRequests, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browser)?

Comment: The limit of concurrent requests is configurable on browsers (for example in Firefox is 4 and the setting is called network.http.pipelining.maxrequests) therefore I think it's worth spreading the image requests across domains. I am not sure whether ajax requests are differentiated but I don't see why it would be different.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There are a lot of things to consider here.  In most situations, I would only choose one cookieless domain/subdomain to host your images such as static.mywebsite.com.  And ideally static files should be hosted by a CDN, but that's another story.

First of all, IE7 allowed only two concurrent connections per host.  But most browsers today allow more than that.  IE8 allows 6 concurrent connections, Chrome allows 6, and Firefox allows 8.

So if your web page only has 6 images, for example, then it'd really be pointless to spread your images across multiple subdomains.

So let's say you have 24 images on a page.  Well, few things in life are free and there's such a thing as death by parallelization.  If you host your images in 4 different subdomains, then that means that every single image could theoretically be downloaded in parallel.  However, it also means that there are 3 additional DNS lookups involved.  And a DNS lookup could be 100 ms, 150 ms, or sometimes longer.  This added delay could easily offset any benefit of parallel downloads.  You can see real-world examples of this by testing sites with http://www.webpagetest.org/

Of course the best solution is to use CSS sprites when possible to cut down on the number of requests.  I talk about that and the inherent overhead of every request in [this article](http://swortham.blogspot.com/2010/03/latency-requests-css-sprites-and-you.html) and [this one](http://www.bucketsoft.com/blog/post/being-clever-with-css-sprites).

**UPDATE**

There's an interesting article from Steve Souders on the subject of sharding domains...

> Most of the U.S. top ten web sites do domain sharding. YouTube uses
>   i1.ytimg.com, i2.ytimg.com, i3.ytimg.com, and i4.ytimg.com. Live
>   Search uses ts1.images.live.com, ts2.images.live.com,
>   ts3.images.live.com, and ts4.images.live.com. Both of these sites are
>   sharding across four domains. What’s the optimal number? **Yahoo!
>   released a study that recommends sharding across at least two, but no
>   more than four, domains. Above four, performance actually degrades.**

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/05/12/sharding-dominant-domains/

Note however that this was written in 2009.  And in 2011 he posted a comment...

> Since newer browsers open more connections per domain, it’s probably
>   better to revise the number downwards. I think 2 is a good compromize,
>   but that’s just a hunch. It’d be great if some production property ran
>   a test to determine the optimal number.

You should also keep in mind that the big reason it's even necessary for the big sites like Yahoo and Amazon to do domain sharding is that their sites are so dynamic.  The images are attached to products or stories which are displayed dynamically.  So it's not feasible for them to use CSS sprites as aggressively as would be optimal.

A site like StackOverflow, however, is light on these sorts of images and they have cut down on the number of requests so much that they don't need to do sharding.  A big step towards making that happen is their usage of this sprites.png image...

http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5

**UPDATE #2**

Steve Souders posted [another update on domain sharding](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/09/05/domain-sharding-revisited/). He repeats much of what I've already mentioned. But the thing that stood out was SPDY and how that should affect your decision.

> Perhaps the strongest argument against domain sharding is that it’s
>   unnecessary in the world of SPDY (as well as HTTP 2.0). In fact,
>   domain sharding probably hurts performance under SPDY. SPDY supports
>   concurrent requests (send all the request headers early) as well as
>   request prioritization. Sharding across multiple domains diminishes
>   these benefits. SPDY is supported by Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE
>   11. If your traffic is dominated by those browsers, you might want to skip domain sharding.

**UPDATE #3 (February 2018)**

As Dean mentioned in the comments below, CSS sprites aren't really buying you very much now with HTTP/2 being supported in modern browsers. But you do have to get an SSL certificate, set up your site to work with HTTPS, and ensure your web server is configured for HTTP/2. Either that, or use a CDN that already has all of that set up for you. Once you've done all of that then you can probably skip both CSS sprites and domain sharding.

Comment: When assets are accessed across multiple domains, is the domain dynamically determined (when it actuality the assets are all stored in the same location)?

Comment: @Jonny - No, the browser won't be aware of that. The domain could be an alias for the same physical files on the server as another domain and even use the same IP address. That would be fine and would allow the browser to download files from two different domains in parallel.

Comment: Should the sprites link here be: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=1635743de786 now?

Comment: To add to Update #2: SPDY was deprecated in favor of HTTP/2 (although it led the way for the new version). Before moving to a CDN, test if your website/server supports HTTP/2. You can test to see if you have support it here: https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test

Comment: Commenting in 2017, because of things like SPDY and HTTP/2, sprites are now less-great, and possibly a bad choice; they add code complexity, and unless you're always using all the images in the sprite, you're sending more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

google chrome have :6, Safari have :5 , mozilla firefox have :8 maximum concurrent get  request to same domain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but a source would be nice.