# How many resources will a browser download from a given domain at a time?

Tags: html, image, optimization

Tried to figure out from firebug and by googling, didn't get any convincing answer.

Comment: Back before Chrome lanched it's _`Chrome -- very fast!`_ campaign. All were serial. Dom loaded, then CSS, the images one by one. After that, they made it load faster or at least look fast (as resources over CDN and in your cache loads faster) by making the process parallel. Parallelism may be their code level thing not a standard constant; and probably function of how many connections can be opened simultaneously to one given URI.

Comment: Looks like a question copied from : https://github.com/h5bp/Front-end-Developer-Interview-Questions

Comment: May be. Back in 2012 html5 boiler plate was nice resource to learn emerging technologies.

Answer (score 33):

Nicely answered in this - [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456325/get-number-of-concurrent-requests-by-browser)

> IE7 allowed only two concurrent connections per host. But most
>   browsers today allow more than that. IE8 allows 6 concurrent
>   connections, Chrome allows 6, and Firefox allows 8.
>
> So if your web page only has 6 images, for example, then it'd really
>   be pointless to spread your images across multiple subdomains.

Comment: Are there any exceptions?

Answer (score 10):

It depends on the browser and how it is setup - firefox has controls for how many download threads to use, for example.

The different browsers (and versions) have different defaults as well.

Comment: thanks @Oded just now i found this link http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/11/performance-research-part-4/

Answer (score 3):

To avoid needlessly overloading servers, browsers limit the number of connections that can be made simultaneously. Depending on which browser, this limit may be as low as two connections per hostname.
source : http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/