# What types of web resources can modern web browsers download in parallel? Also, what can't be downloaded in parallel?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, http, cross-browser

What types of web resources can modern web browsers download in parallel?  Also, what can't be downloaded in parallel?

Most answers on StackOverflow address "how many resources can be downloaded in parallel", but not "what". ([Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583172/how-many-resources-will-a-browser-download-from-a-given-domain-at-a-time))

Examples of things that cannot be downloaded in parallel:

1. CSS files specified by "@import" ([Explanation](https://dev.to/jasmin/how-does-import-works-in-css-what-is-the-pros-and-cons-136c))
2. `<script>` without "async" or "defer"
3. The HTML file itself (e.g., we can't pre-parse `<body>` while parsing `<head>`)
4. What else?

Thanks!

Comment: _What_ browsers try to download in parallel differs per browser engine, of which there aren't that many anymore. I would say that anything, that can _logically_ be downloaded in parallel, will. Why this general statement? Well, if I were to design a browser, I would create a central hub for all download sub-requests and order them there by importance/precedence, after checking the cache. Then I would download as many requests in parallel as is efficient. This can, obviously, quickly get very complicated. That's the best answer I can give, but it is probably not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: Have a look at the [web developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools), and specifically the "Network" tab. There you can see _what_ the browser downloads and _when_. Dig a bit deeper and you can find a "waterfall" that shows you in great detail what is being downloaded and rendered. This is best viewed on a desktop.

Comment: This was an interview question, and I was asked to provide 10 simple examples (in addition to what were listed above).  I probably can't ask him to go into the "Network" tab and check it himself.

Comment: I must admin I answered what _can_ be downloaded in parallel, and not what _cannot_. I can think of one other thing that cannot be downloaded in parallel: The [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) in a CSS file. Making up 6 more like this is hard. Example No. 3, in your question. is a bit weird: "parsing" isn't "downloading". Maybe the interview question wasn't just about downloading? Maybe it was in general about things that could not be done in parallel? Anyway, it is a difficult interview question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few more examples of resources that cannot be downloaded in parallel:

- Background images defined defined within a CSS file aren't discovered until the browser downloads and parses the CSS file
- Fonts defined with @font-face rules defined within a CSS files aren't discovered until the browser downloads and parses the CSS file
- fetch() functions defined within a JavaScript file aren't discovered until the browser downloads and parses the JavaScript file