# Concurrent requests in ASP.Net development server

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, httprequest

How many Concurrent requests are allowed in asp.net development server? I am using asp.net 4.0

Comment: btw maximum value of current request is 6 in performance counter...why is it so? i am not able to make concurrent requests > 6 ....please help

Comment: Well, instead of asking *"why does it matter?"* it's probably just better to [learn about options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i tried this in both asp.net development server and iis7...same result...tell me why counter is limited to 6?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i got the answer...it depends upon browser...see this line "IE7 allowed only two concurrent connections per host. But most browsers today allow more than that. IE8 allows 6 concurrent connections, Chrome allows 6, and Firefox allows 8"...and these links :- [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456325/get-number-of-concurrent-requests-by-browser) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse)...thanks 4 the help...i ll going to use sharding as explained in this [link3](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/05/12/sharding-dominant-domains/)

Answer (score 2):

What is your OS? Not exactly specific to Dev server:

- [Windows 8 / IIS 8 Concurrent Requests Limit](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2012/11/13/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit.aspx)
- references [this from IIS.net site](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2008/05/01/understanding-iis7-request-restrictions-on-windows-vista.aspx), a bit old but again, describes limits *based on OS*

*Server OSes* don't have **preset  limits**....

Comment: may be its because of OS...right now i am using windows 7...i ll going to check this on windows server 2008...thanks btw..!!

Comment: see [this screenshot](http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/8758/igsw.jpg) ...i tested this on windows server 2008...iis7 with .net 4.0.....see i marked maximum requests with a circle...its showing six request at max..and an arrow is showing current requests...can you explain me what this means??

Comment: @pgmanutd If I'm not mistaken it's showing you the *maximum requests IIS has received given the time frame* (of 1:40) - **not** some limit or anything.

Comment: yes i know...but as i said i am not able to make requests > 6...i tried opening same webpage twice or thrice....requests from later pages are going into queue, but if i close pages which i opened earlier then only these queued request are getting processed...do you have any other way of checking how many requests are being processed by IIS?

Comment: @pgmanutd - as in errors? Or are you just saying you can't generate a test of > 6 requests? If the web page you are testing creates 6 requests (e.g. page + 5 images), then your _current_ request is 6. Is caching (browser used to test) in play? Also see this about `Requests Current` and more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998579.aspx#scalenetchapt15_topic12  hth....

Comment: yes i am not able to generate a test of > 6 requests...i also disabled caching..but same result... **Requests Current** in performance monitor is staying at 6...see this line "Requests are rejected when ASP.NET\Requests Current exceeds the requestQueueLimit (default = 5000) attribute for <processModel> element defined in the Machine.config file. This can happen when the server is under very heavy load"...lol in my case **Requests Current** is staying at 6 (5000 is very far)....

Comment: @pgmanutd Well, you can (a) write a "http request tester" and create requests programmatically - this way you take out browser caching, or (b) save time and use [**`WCAT`**](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/05/wcat-63-(x64)) to stress test your server.