# disable browser ajax throttling

Tags: ajax, concurrency, browser, throttling

Is it possible to disable browser-based ajax throttling?

Users of a website I've written are unfortunately unable to upgrade from IE8, so websockets are out; therefore, the only way to update is to blast with many ajax requests.

I would rather not write redundant code that combines ajax requests simply to work around this issue.

If it this possible, how can it be done?  (IE8, Chrome primary concern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of concurrent requests in a browser is only limited on the same domain.  If you are able to create a number of subdomains that can accept some of the ajax requests, then you could increase the number of concurrent requests in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware that disabling the throttle is possible, but many browsers only limit request by the domain. Using different sub-domains can help speed up the requests, but come at the operational cost of having more than one sub-domain to hit.

Here is some more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456934/1165635

Since you don't want to rewrite the code to make batched requests, you could possibly rely on something like promises or deferred actions to wait until all the requests are done then continue. Though this doesn't actually help solve your specific problem.