# why is my page loading so slowly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-preloader

My website: http://jgyboatparty.com/

is loading horrifically slow  and I cant figure out why. I have compressed the images as much as possible and made the video file available as a webm, and yet with a fresh reload the page is taken minutes to load!

Am i missing something here, as for some reason when I look at when elements are loaded, some of the images dont even start loading until 30 seconds in. This all means that my loader goes on for a while. (I have a wait until images loaded function)

Any advice would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have any code? It'd be nice to see what you're loading and how it's being loaded.

Comment: because of video in the page

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because i believe it is just to promote itself

Comment: no buddy  its a genuine question. I simply cant get get it to load any quicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web is full of useful tools that shall aid you in this:

[Google pageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) for one and [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) another. Make use of these tools to analyse what could be causing your site to be slow.

Also, ensure all of your'e images are properly optimised. Another tool again that may help is [Tinypng](https://tinypng.com/).

Google's Inspector can also be very useful to help diagnose bottlenecks and so forth. Here's another link that may help you:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/

Also, I see you are using various libraries such as owl carousel, Parallax, and fitvids to name three. I would look to try and at least use cdn versions: a CDN is a way to deliver content from your website or mobile application to people more quickly and efficiently, based on their geographic location.

Also, look into lazy loading of your images.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have enough juice to your server? When pinging you server it takes 71ms, and when i am pinging your govrment's server it's approximately 31ms.

When i am checking the network tab for your website an image which is about 155kb big, takes about 1.2 seconds to load.

Steps to improve your speed might be minify all your scripts.
Do not load all of your content at once.

Answer (score 0):

Open your broswer's dev tools and find out.

Browsers only allow 4 (max) concurrent downloads from 1 domain. So while the browser is downloading those, it blocks the others.

[image]

Move your scrips/ images to a sub domain or a cdn or just do something listed in the post below.

[Get number of concurrent requests by browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456325/get-number-of-concurrent-requests-by-browser)