# Ajax ping script multiple IP's

Tags: php, ajax, multithreading, apache

I have a page that shows the status of a list of IP addresses.
It uses ajax to call a ping script for each IP.

What I am finding is that it can only do about 6 at a time even though ALL of the IP's (about 30 of them) are requested at the same time from the javascript.

How can I get them to all ping at once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Web Server is not accepting more than 6 requests, you should check it.
Additionally, you could use Firebug to see if all the requests have been triggered in the same time and what is happening with each of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on how many concurrent requests you can send out. Also see here: [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse)

One trick websites use to make their serving faster, is to limit the amount of requests needed. They also put stuff (images) in a a separate (sub)domain, because you get another 3 (or 6) requests on that domain.

In your case you can try to fit them into 1 call, or direct them to several subdomains.

(to be clear: although the server CAN have a limit, the limit you are reaching here is the requests your browser sends out. in IE it seems you can be limited to another (2?) number, see the link I provided)

Answer (score 0):

You can do only 6...does it take too long?

Comment: why not POST a list of ip`s to the script and get 1 response rather than 30