# What's the maximum number of simultaneous connections a browser will make?

Tags: html, css, browser

What's the maximum number of concurrent connections that a browser will make to download resources specified in a HTML page? Does it vary from browser to browser/connection speed?

Comment: No, it varies according to browser type and the domain you're requesting from. IIRC, most modern browsers allow 6 per domain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse)

Comment: This is not about AJAX requests. While the limits may be the same for ajax and on-page resources, this question concern the latter.

Comment: it's the same - httprequests. Read the according answers and you will be enlightened.

Comment: I think this is a better phrasing of the question which is likely to be generally useful, so I don't think this should be closed, particularly as I managed to find a nice source which answers it :)

Comment: I agree with @PaulDixon. This question is far different than the AJAX question despite the answers: consider the relevance when searching for something like "maximum browser connections". I vote to reopen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The short answer is "about 4 to 6 connections per domain"

For more details, check out this great [roundup of how many parallel connections each browser will make to a given domain](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/03/20/roundup-on-parallel-connections/)

Results summarized below...

```
+----------------------+------------+------------+
|Browser               |  HTTP/1.1  |  HTTP/1.0  |
+----------------------+------------+------------+
|IE 6,7                | 2 ##       | 4 ####     |
|IE 8                  | 6 ######   | 6 ######   |
|Firefox 2             | 2 ##       | 8 ######## |
|Firefox 3             | 6 ######   | 6 ######   |
|Safari 3,4            | 4 ####     | 4 ####     |
|Chrome 1,2            | 6 ######   | ?          |
|Chrome 3              | 4 ####     | 4 ####     |
|Chrome 4+             | 6 ######   | ?          |
|iPhone 2              | 4 ####     | ?          |
|iPhone 3              | 6 ######   | ?          |
|iPhone 4              | 4 ####     | ?          |
|Opera 9.63,10.00alpha | 4 ####     | 4 ####     |
|Opera 10.51+          | 8 ######## | ?          |
+----------------------+------------+------------+
```