# Symfony not send response if previous process is work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

I send few ajax requests to my site. First running creating document, others check him status. But symfony not respond while first process is working. All processes wait in queue while end first. If look in log i see:

> request.INFO: Matched route "start creating". work first request.INFO:
>   Matched route "check" work first request.INFO: Matched route "check"
>   work first .... event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to
>   listener for first process event.DEBUG: Notified event
>   "kernel.response" to listener for second process etc

Why symfony very strange processes requests?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem in php session mechanism.

```
session_write_close();
```

fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

It is not symfony, but your browser which limits number of simultaneous connections to the same domain. See [What's the maximum number of simultaneous connections a browser will make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185618/whats-the-maximum-number-of-simultaneous-connections-a-browser-will-make)

Comment: No this not browser. If it was browser log not contains requests in process first requests, but they have