# Max limit on number of concurrent ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, performance, http

I have a website that fetches approximately 20 pages, each page is different. Currently, it takes about 1.2 minutes to load.

Some days back this task only took 11-15 seconds. Now it takes 1.2 minutes. What can be the reason for sudden change?

Is there any solution other than merging some of these to reduce the number of requests? Can the limit of number of requests be somehow altered?

[image]

The above screenshot is from Firebug. the gray portions of the bars represent "Blocking".

Comment: In jQuery, you can use the "beforeSend" event to abort a Ajax-request if the limit has been reached.

Comment: Did the size of the pages (length in Bytes) change? Open the "Net" tab in the browser's dev tools to see where the time is spent.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to find out. The main problem seems to be that results are now coming sequentially. Try it urself. http://compare.buyhatke.com/products/apple-ipod-touch

Comment: That is true. The browsers are **blocking** the Ajax-requests. It seems that they are enforcing some limit.

Comment: So, what could be the reason ? How can I avoid it ?

Comment: If you could combine those requests into one, that would be great. Btw, you can get more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse The max number of connections per hostname appears to be 6 in most browsers.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Does providing lots of conditions in .htaccess may be a problem for this ? I mean it would go through those conditions again n again. Can it sufficiently lower the performance ?

Comment: The process is slow because the browsers do not allow more than 6 concurrent Ajax-requests to the same host name.

Comment: So, I think , using 3 sub-domains will then resolve the issue. I will distribute them among three sub-domains. That as a result will enhance our performance and speed

Comment: Yes, sub-domains should do the trick.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas But we forgot an important point, that, ajax request is not possible between cross-domains

Comment: It is possible with CORS. Your web-server has to provide a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I tried CORS. Can you please, help me in this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919732/setting-up-access-control-for-cross-domain-ajax-request

Comment: @ŠimeVidas How can CDN servers help me in speeding up the response ? Since CORS is not supported by my server

Comment: You can manually implement CORS on your server. You just have to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the HTTP-response. Read the thread that I suggested in your other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody should have suggested me to use multi-CURL instead. In that I just need to make a call to a single PHP file and that will automatically call to each one of them, that too in parallel.

Take a look [here](http://www.rustyrazorblade.com/2008/02/curl_multi_exec/)

Comment: Please include the important parts of the linked content in your answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

Most webkit browsers will only allow for 2 simultaneous AJAX connections at any given time.  The best practice would be to have the website receive the data as a JSON string, and for the JavaScript to then put all of the data where it belongs.  Given your screenshot, I would assume that the backend is all in PHP.

Start with json_encode() on the PHP side, and eval() on the JavaScript side, from there it should be a walk in the park.

Comment: How can CDN servers help me in speeding up the response ?