# Setting up access-control for cross-domain ajax request

Tags: performance, http, .htaccess, access-control, cors

I have three sub-domains namely, `a.xyz.com, b.xyz.com, c.xyz.com.` Now, I have about 20 ajax request to be made on body onload of `a.xyz.com.`

So, I thought of distributing 20 requests equally among the three domains above. I tried it through this piece of snippet in .htaccess of `b.xyz.com` and `c.xyz.com`. However, the request from a.xyz.com to any other sub-domain is still getting dumped.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://a.xyz.com,http://b.xyz.com,http://b.xyz.com
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods : POST,GET,OPTIONS
</FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
```

I have placed the above `.htaccess` file in my subdomains `b.xyz.com` and `c.xyz.com`.

So, can anyone predict whats wrong in my approach ?

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to allow cross domain on all xyz.com subdomains:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(.+\.)?(xyz\.com)$" ORIGIN_DOMAIN=$0
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ORIGIN_DOMAIN}e env=ORIGIN_DOMAIN
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST,GET,OPTIONS"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```