# Calling function in loop containing call to function containing a promise does not execute all the required times

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a for loop that calls a function in Javascript (getItemsForFolderID) for each item in that array(subfolders.data). 
In this case there are 80 items in the array, but I can only see log statements for 6...
getItemsForFolderID contains a promise that makes a call to a function that returns a promise and calls a REST API retrieving items (this works!)

Anyone know why only 6 calls are made? I get 80 console entries for `console.log('Getting Items for: ' + subfolders.data[j].id)` but only six of either 
`console.log('No items for folder: ' + folderID);` or `console.log('There were items');`

Here is the loop:

```
for (var j = 0; j < subfolders.data.length; j++) {
    console.log('Getting Items for: ' + subfolders.data[j].id);
    getItemsForFolderID(subfolders.data[j].id);
}
```

And the function we're calling:

```
function getItemsForFolderID(folderID) {
  var getItemsPromise = getItemsForFolderIDFromAPI(folderID);
  getItemsPromise.then(function(items) {
    if(items.data.length === 0) {
        console.log('No items for folder: ' + folderID);
    }
    else {
        console.log('There were items');
    }
  });
}



var RateLimiter = require('request-rate-limiter');

var limiter = new RateLimiter({rate: 100, interval: 60, backoffCode: 429, backoffTime: 15, maxWaitingTime: 2600
});

function getItemsForFolderIDFromAPI(folderID) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        limiter.request({
            url: url + '/' + folderID,
            method: 'get',
            headers: headers
        }).then(function (response) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(response.body));
        }).catch(function (err) {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the network tab (developer tools)? Can you tell whether 80 HTTP requests were made? What about responses? What do your server logs show? What exactly does `getItemsForFolderIDFromAPI()` look like?

Comment: Apologies @MarkMeyer I fixed that. It was a typo

Comment: @Pointy I am running this code as a nodejs app from VS Code and I'm not aware how to view outgoing HTTP Requests there. I get responses for six requests, but any more.

Comment: @Pointy I added that function to help diagnose the issue

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: may be browser blocking requests.. check this our https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Comment: @VishalRajole Thanks for this! Was not aware! I'm running the solution through the command line with node so how do I know what browser I'm using? Is the browser even a factor?

Comment: @Bergi Is this bad practice? Could you link me to an article describing better practice? I'm interested in improving :)

Comment: @MattTheHack Yes it is, and I already linked the answers that should help you to avoid it.

Comment: @MattTheHack If you're running this in node, then you are not using a browser and Vishal's comment does not apply

Comment: @MattTheHack I was assuming you are using browser. Anyway what node version you are using.  Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060869/why-is-node-js-only-processing-six-requests-at-a-time