# PHP Multiple Ajax requests: First request block second request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, multithreading, asynchronous

I've got 2 ajax requests on one page. I ran first request and separately start second one. But second one stops working after the first has been run. And continue when first is over. 
First requst take long time - something like 30 - 60 seconds and in this time I need second request to show logs what happens with first request. I try to use async: true but it's not help me.

Here it's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval( function()
        { asyncGet('log.php') }, 1000
    );

    function asyncGet(addr) {
        $.ajax({
            url: addr,
            async: true,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#loadLog').html(response);
            }
        });
    }

    function getConn(addr) {
        $.ajax({
            url: addr,
            async: true,
            success: function (response) {
                stopGet();
            }
        });
    }


</script>

<div id="loadLog" class="lLog"></div>
```

and I call first ajax request in this way: getConn('main.php'); from function when press button.
Second request it's running, but not show respons before first request complete.

I wil attach image from firebug.
main.php - is request that take longer time.
log.php - is the logger that is blocked.

[image]

Would really appreciate some pointers to where I'm going wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse

Comment: Yes :)
If main.php is not running - log is loading very fast every second. Here is the code:
<?php
 require 'config.php';
 isLogged();

 $log = run_q("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE user_id = $logged[id] AND revision = $logged[revision] ORDER BY id DESC");
 while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($log)) {
  echo '&nbsp; => ' . $r['event'] . ' ' . $r['date'] . '<br />';
 }
?>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be a problem with session. Check out this [post](http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/). Suppose you may need to close session in your main.php as fast as possible.

Comment: I just had one of those “Awwwwuuuu” moments. I honestly in 6 years of PHP never knew this. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hey, I have similar problem but I am not using session. session is used as global but not for the functions that are invoked. I use database to retrieve results. Please help.

Comment: @JunaidAtique it is not required for your code to use session directly . It might be started on each request automatically even if it is not needed.

Comment: @FAngel thanks I figured that out. I was using session as global. Now I have made it to controller specific. Thanks for you time.