# window.open in jquery ajax success callback blocks subsequent ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, callback

I have an AJAX call setting some session variables on a server.

When the session variables are set, in the success callback, I'm opening a new window to the appropriate page.

```
window.open("../reports/" + data.d, "report");
```

Sometimes, it takes a *long* time to render. Making it render faster is, at this time, beyond my control.

My concern is that as it attempts to render the html in this window, it's blocking all other ajax requests. It queues them up and once the window is finally rendered, they execute.

I've already tried using setTimeout but it doesn't seem to work (apparently because jQuery.ajax is already occupying the "thread").

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers limit the number of concurrent connections

See 
[How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse)

and [browserscope's chart](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network)

Comment: I don't think this is the case here. Its in the success callback at this point and if it did 'count' as an open connection it is the only one.