# What is the maximum number of thread allowed to run on a web page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, extjs

I have developed a page using ExtJS and ASP.NET. The page got multiple widgets. Each widget sends multiple AJAX request at the time of load. I assume each AJAX request runs over a new thread. I just want to understand:

1. How many such threads are allowed to run from a single window? How many request a broswer can send to the server, without getting queued at the broswer itself. I know request can be queued at the server side depending on various parameters.
2. Does this behavior changes from browser to browser ?
3. Is there any way to trace the number of active request?

**I am not talking about number of threads that can run on Server-Side. I am not talking about number of request a server can process.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse)

Answer (score 0):

> How many such threads are allowed to run from a single window?

It depends on your server's hardware capabilities and configuration.

> Does this behavior changes from browser to browser ?

No.

> Is there any way to trace the number of active request?

**Microsoft**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420(v=vs.100).aspx

**Examples & Tips**

http://www.dotnetperls.com/trace

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. How can server decide the number of request (assuming each request is a new thread) a client (browser) can send? Server can decide the number of request it will process at a time. But I dont think server can decide number of request each browser can send.

Comment: The client can send multiple request to multiple server. So checking number of active request at server side is not an option. I want to check how many request is been sent from this window & how many of them is active.

Comment: There no limit on client side. suppose you sent 5 requests at a time and server has capability of handling only 4 threads at a time, 4 will be processed immediately but 5th request will have to wait until it finds an vacant spot to be executed.

Comment: you should be able to do that with tracing.

Answer (score 0):

A server typically can handle several simultaneous requests, even with a small number of threads.

On IIS you configure this using

```
<system.web>
    <applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="50" maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" requestQueueLimit="5000"/>
</system.web>
```

Refer: [Microsoft best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549.aspx)

On a browser when using javascript, you should know that javascript doesn't have any multi-threading capabilities.

The number of simultaneous ajax(or other) requests to a server is browser dependent. 
Usually 2, 6, 8 threads are allowed per domain name. This should not bother you too much, cause the rest will be queued.

Refer: [BrowserScope for the latest network data](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network)