# Trigger multiple Ajax requests at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function on jQuery who by onclick event send post request and change value in table row.

How i can do it mass? For example, i have button "Check all" on click this, i call function. 
I want to click-once summoned all the `check` and then they started to be executed

pseudo code:

```
<ul>
  <li id=1>text1</li>
  <li id=2>text2</li>
  <li id=3>text3</li>
</ul>

<button id="checkall">check all</button>
<script>

function check(id) { /* ... */ }'

on('click', '#checkall', {
  $("ul li").each(function() { 
    check(this.attr('id'));
  });
});

</script>
```

Yes, i know thats its stupid idea, but, how i can do it? ^_^

Thanks.

Comment: Why you used `Threads` word in your title ?

Comment: Are you saying that clicks on individual items send individual (Ajax?) requests - and you've already imlemented this - but you want the "check all" option to send a single (Ajax?) request that includes all of the data at once? Or do you want the "check all" to send multiple requests in a loop?

Comment: Yes, i say that clicks on individual items send individual (on Ajax) requests, but you want the "check all" to send multiple requests in a loop?

Comment: @pXL thought that this is the best word that describes the problem

Comment: @AlexKiselev: But WTH do [threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) have to do with your problem?

Comment: can you show your `onclick` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will trigger the `li`'s click event (which you said you have already setup)

```
on('click', '#checkall', {
  $("ul li").trigger('click');
});
```

You should notice there is a limit on ajax that you can run at the same time,
Please view the following [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse)

if you  need to run some function before triggering the click,
you could do something like this:

```
$("ul li").each(function() { 
    // Your code here
    $(this).trigger('click');
  });
```

all in all, i think you are going the wrong way with this.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this :

```
var check = function() { ... };

$('#checkall').on('click',function() {
  $("ul li").each(function() { 
    check(this);//to check it all use your function
    //other code
  });
});
```

I used `this` because I don't know which function are calling and what variable are you passing to.

Comment: @roasted - It could be "check" as in "test" (unrelated to checkboxes). But yes, it's not the clearest of questions.