# Xhr Polling Test

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a problem with xhr-polling.Xhr have 5 connections limit.When I looking for a solution,I found that example on github.

https://gist.github.com/jmyrland/4639758

There are 2 codes,I am thinking the first code (ex.js) is server,second code is client(ex-test.js) But when I add this line : "require(socket.io-client)" to the client code,I'm getting "require is not defined" error.How can I use require command on client ?

Ps:I installed socket.io-client.

Comment: Is your client a node js application ?

Comment: @mguimard yes I am using socket.io with this code

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com:8440/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

Comment: I mean : do you run your client code with nodejs or within a browser like firefox or chrome ?

Comment: Then your client is **not** a nodejs application. Consequently, you cannot use node's require. You'll need to modify the code taken from the gist (which is a nodejs client application) to use the socket.io library. By the way, you won't be able to call require("http") to modify the http agent max socket value. Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse

Comment: I read the link.I understood this is a browser limit.What can I do other than that ?