# Why my JQuery ajax functions waits indefinitely

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery ajax function calls to load the data. When I am testing in Chrome sometimes it doesn't call the request complete function and sometimes it works. Please let me know what could be the reason.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: data_url,
    type: 'post',
    data: ""
});
request.done(function(result)
{
    console.log("Done");
}
```

The URL and everything are correct because it works sometime when I click refresh. Is it something that I need to pass some end code when I am sending the stream from browser?

In server side, I am using PHP echo function to send encoded JSON.

Comment: p/s: Use `GET` if you're simply fetching data from the server, and not modifying anything on the other end :)

Comment: use fail() too or use always() and check for error message

Comment: Thank you @Terry, it works when I changed to GET.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not seem to be wrong. One problem I sometimes ran into myself was that web browsers limit the number of concurrent requests to servers. So if you have a breakpoint set in server code, you easily run into the problem you describe during debugging sessions. See also [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is the only function executed onload of the window. There is no other AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend is hanging. The reason it sometimes works when you refresh is that the browser cancels the request when you refresh, causing the xhr to finish.

You can try with curl from the command line to make sure:

```
$ curl -iX POST --data "" data_url
```

Comment: It is the local server and if I type the URL in browser directly then, get the response immediately.