# How many asynchronous calls can be processed at the same time by IIS from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, iis

I am using asp classic in my application. In this I am doing one ajax request which will continuously fetch data from a socket and store that in a session, now a further ajax request will fetch that data from session and javascript will accept that data.

But when I try then my subsequent request it does not goes to the server. So can any body tell me is this possible to send subsequent ajax request to IIS while few ajax requests are still running . You can say it like creating a multithreaded environment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse

Comment: When you make a call via js, who controls the calls is the browser, and not IIS.

Comment: @HugoTostes  That mean IIS is capable of handling multiple ajax request from same user and can run those request parallel?

Comment: No. read this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse

Comment: @HugoTostes I am using vbscript at server side to do that, so could you please tell me is vbscript able to process multiple request for the same user or it will queue the further request for the first to complete.