# SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS in iOS when downloading over HTTP/2

Tags: ios, http2, urlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

In iOS, how to limit the maximum number of parallel download requests that are multiplexed over a single connection in HTTP/2.

I am observing that 100's of requests are sent in parallel when downloading .ts files of a m3u8 video. There is a limit on the maximum number of request that our HTTP/2 server can handle. I tried:

> sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 3

but later realized that it is applicable only for HTTP/1 as there will be multiple connection only in HTTP/1 whereas there will be always only 1 connection per host in HTTP/2.

I came across SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS property of HTTP/2 as mentioned in this post: [Does the per-host connection limit is raised with HTTP/2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835972/does-the-per-host-connection-limit-is-raised-with-http-2). But not sure how to set it's value in iOS.