# Chrome is Stalling Requests for 17 sec in Angular 5 Application

Tags: angular, google-chrome

In my angular 5 app the requests are getting stalled by 17 secs in chrome. And the same is working fine in Firefox. I searched some doc and found that chrome allows only 6 connection simultaneously.  Is there any way by which I can solve this. **Did angular has anything to do with this?** .

[image: One sample request timer]

Answer (score 1):

when you use Https it have the limitation that you can only send max 6 concurrent request on Chrome. so in order to send more use **Http/2**. follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835972/is-the-per-host-connection-limit-raised-with-http-2#:%7E:text=It%20is%20virtually%20unlimited%20in,Firefox%27s%20default%20value%20for%20network.)

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I will check this and reply here.

Comment: I have checked this but  in my case I am using windows authentication so what I found is  I cant use Http/2