# Problem Understanding Network Waterfalls | Chrome Devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tcp, google-chrome-devtools

While testing a client's site I saw this in the Network Waterfalls tab of Chrome Devtools:

[image]

I was under the impression that browsers could only make 6 connections at a time (read somewhere that this might now be 10), so I don't understand how there are so many connections active simultaneously.

At this point I'm pretty sure my fundamentals are wrong, but I don't know which. Would really appreciate it if someone could explain why there are more than 6 (or 10) connections being made here.

Comment: [Is the per-host connection limit raised with HTTP/2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36847527)

Comment: You're right! I had a feeling it might be H2 but didn't wanna jump to conclusions. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @wOxxOm for answering the question in the comments - This is indeed a situation with HTTP/2. Here is a link to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36847527

To verify this, head on over Network Waterfalls, right click on the titles (Name, Type, Initiator etc.) and click on `Protocols`. A new column will pop up showing the protocols used to form the connections. In my case, some files were requested with `h2`, meaning HTTP/2. As the answer linked states, this allows the browser to form virtually unlimited concurrent requests to the same domain.