# Limit of async calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Is there a limit to how many async function can be fired simultaneously in javascript? I need to use a large number of async functions in react native.

Comment: You can fire as many async function you want until it goes out of memory. It depends on the hardware used by who execute the script and some browser can also set their own limit.

By the way, there isn't any reason to fire many async functions to accomplish a task. Probably there is a problem in the design of your application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse)

Comment: @criz there is a different limit per browser on how many concurrent http requests can be made. OP needs to use control flow patterns in order to execute a large number of async petitions.