# how to control multiple ajax requests in laravel 5.2

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, jquery-ajaxq

I am working on an application where different ajax requests fires depending upon different actions.

For example, there is a chat window having send button. When i click on that button an empty message is sent with ajax, successfully. It work nice. But when I hit the send button too many times, at start some requests respond 200 (ok) but then it respond 500 (internal server error). Due to this the other requests that are going continuously like updateLastActivity also disturb.
The preview of the error in developer's tool is:
Whoops like something went wrong.

Note: When I make this chat system in core PHP, it work fine. There is no internal server error when I send too may requests.

Here is the code I am using

```
    //the following code is used to send the message
 $(document).on('click','.send_message_bt',function(event){
     event.preventDefault();

        var id=$(this).data('id');
        var name=$(this).data('name');
        var message=$("#message_field-"+id).val();



    $.ajax({
        //headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
         headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': {!! json_encode(csrf_token()) !!} },
        url:'{{route('user.sendmessage')}}',
        type:'POST',
        data:{
          id:id,
        message:message
           },
        success:function(data,status){
        //clear the message field value
        $("#message_field-"+id).val('');

        //update the chat history
        fetchChatHistory(id,name);


    },
        error:function(response){
           if(response.status==401){
                  alert('You are not logged in!');
                  window.location=window.location.href;
                   }

           }

});

});
```

here is the back end code

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request){
    $message=new Userchatmessage();
     $message->message=$request->message;
     $message->sender_id=Auth::user()->id;
     $message->receiver_id=$request->id;
     $message->save();
     return response('success');
}
```

How to fix this issue.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the error message when you get 500?

Comment: Internal server error is displaing on console.

Comment: Yes. Please copy and paste the console logs.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not a problem with Laravel or anything, but with your browser. Each browser has a maximum amount of simultaneous connections it will open for a certain domain.

Read more about this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse) and [here](http://www.browserscope.org/).

If you want to make a realtime chat application, consider using something like [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [Socket.io](https://socket.io/).

Comment: Then why it don't give error when i make the system in core php instead of Laravel.

Comment: Because the problem is with simultaneous requests. A single PHP file will return a response really quick, where a complete framework like Laravel is a little bit slower.

Comment: probably because Laravel goes through a bunch of function call stacks (that may cause php out of memory/timeout) just to process a request, while in your core php, that's just that.

Comment: Can i use sockets for all of my real time work like...making real time notifications...chat...maintain real time online status etc.

Comment: @habib Yes, this is certainly possible! Just read up on some use cases, tutorials and you'll be implementing those things in no time!

Answer (score 1):

Async and await can help. Let an async function

```
async function doAjax(){
    await runFirstAjaxCall();
    await runAfterFirstAjaxCallSuccess();
    ....
    ....
}
doAjax();
```