# How i can enforce function to wait until foreach code finish in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I try to update on  group members value for each group , and after that i want to return new groups updated .i do this by adding each group to result array i declared before .

but  i always  got the empty result in result array .
Anyone know how i can to make execution sequentially,do not goes to return statement first

This is my code :

```
searchGroups: async (groupIdsList, accountId) => {
  var result = [];
  return Group.find({
    _id: { $in: groupIdsList },
    accountId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(accountId),
  }).then((groupList) => {
    groupList.forEach(function (group) {
      groupService
        .getMembersUserDetails(
          group.members,
          mongoose.Types.ObjectId(accountId)
        )
        .then((members) => {
          group.members = members;
          result.push(group);
        });
    });

    return result;
  });
};
```

Comment: need something like Promise.All() take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53798589/await-loop-vs-promise-all

Comment: The await keyword
The real advantage of async functions becomes apparent when you combine it with the await keyword. This can be put in front of any async promise-based function to pause your code on that line until the promise fulfills, then return the resulting value. In the meantime, other code that may be waiting for a chance to execute gets to do so.

You can use await when calling any function that returns a Promise, including web API functions.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return many Promises in a loop and wait for them all to do other stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426740/how-to-return-many-promises-in-a-loop-and-wait-for-them-all-to-do-other-stuff)

Comment: there are many, many Stack Overflow questions regarding Javascript promises generated inside a loop.  which of them have you researched and why do they not solve your specific problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `async`, you could leverage `await` and simplify the code like this.

Also note that forEach doesn't support promises so you need to use either `for..of` or `Promise.all` with `.map` if you could do things oin parallel.

Something like this.

```
searchGroups: async (groupIdsList, accountId) => {
  const groupList = await  Group.find({"_id": {"$in": groupIdsList}, "accountId": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(accountId)});
  return Promise.all(groupList.map(async group => {
    group.members = await groupService.getMembersUserDetails(group.members, mongoose.Types.ObjectId(accountId));
    return group;
  }));
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish Modi  for your answer , its returned  updated group member , but the  main property for group does not returned , for example  group name ,id ..etc does i need to make map for all group properties ?

Comment: @AmmarMousa in that case you need to do a then and add members in group and return that instead. updated my answer. You could also use `async/await`

Comment: @ Ashish Modi  Thank you very much , it toke  too much time from me , thanks again :))

Comment: @AshishModi I made a stylistic improvement to your answer, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to convert your *forEach* into a for... of or any flat loop, while adding an *await* to your *getMembersUserDetails*:

```
    searchGroups: async (groupIdsList, accountId) => {
      var result = [];

      return Group.find({
        _id: { $in: groupIdsList },
        accountId: mongoose.Types.ObjectI(accountId)
      }).then(async groupList => {
        for (var group of groupList) {
          await groupService.getMembersUserDetails(group.members,mongoose.Types.ObjectId(accountId))
            .then(members => {
              group.members = members;
              result.push(group);
            });
        }
        return result;
      });
    };
```

Then, use the await operator when calling your function:

```
await searchGroups(groupIdsList, accountId);
```

Comment: This has the same problem.

Comment: This will probably work now with the edit (if you may the function `async` that the `await` is in), but it serializes the database requests, when they don't need to be serialized which may be much slower.  You're also mixing `await` and `.then()` which usually isn't preferred.  See Ashish's answer for a better way.

Comment: Fare point, perhaps one can make subsequent calls without awaiting them and then use a Join operator to await them all together.

Comment: Never had a problem with awaiting a .then as it's clear that you are awaiting its return value.

Comment: @EliasFaraone awaiting a `.then()` isn't problematic, it's stylistically unnecessary since you can convert the `.then()` into another `await` statement and avoid nesting closures.

Comment: Along with what Patrick said, that `await groupService.getMembersUserDetails(...)` will throw a syntaxError because it's not in an `async` function.  That's the other part of my comment.  I will remove my downvote if you at least add the necessary `async` to make it code that would work.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have added the async, missed that you're right.

Comment: OK, now this is an answer that should work.  I don't think it's optimal from a performance point of view because you've serialize each of the database requests and I don't think it's optimal from a style point of view because of the mixing of `await` and `.then()`.  I removed my downvote, but my upvote goes to Ashish's answer as my preferred implementation.