# Is there a way using which I could execute ajax request for n number of times in regular chunk size?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Function defined below is for creating the promise object with multiple dynamic ajax request execution,

```
function executeChunkwise(start, end, parameterObj, batchnumber){
    var allPromises = [];

    for(var i=start;i<end;i++) { 
        (function(index){
                allPromises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "myurl",
                        data: 'queryparameter=' + parameterObj[index],
                        method: 'POST',
                        success: function (response) {
                            $.each(response, function() {
                                idObj = [];
                                $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                                    idObj.push(this.id);
                                });
                                data.push({
                                   'dynamicVar': parameterObj[index],
                                   'products': idObj
                                });
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            resolve(true)
                        }
                    }).done(function(response){
                        resolve(true);
                    });
                }));
        })(i);
    }
    //execute all promised ajax requests and pass the finalised reponse as data to create 
    //the json file via new ajax request.
    Promise.all(allPromises).then((result) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "jsonGenerator.php",
            data: {
                response: JSON.stringify(data),
                batchnumber: batchnumber
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (item) {
                //success
            }
        });
   })
}
```

Which is further getting executed for the chunk size of 1000, on document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    val = <?php echo json_encode($records) ?>;
    chunk=1000;
    batchnumber = 1;
    for (start=0,end=val.length; start<end; start+=chunk) {
        var batchend = (start+chunk > end) ? end : start+chunk;
        executeChunkwise(start, batchend, val, batchnumber); 
        batchnumber+=1;
    }
})
```

In result the strange error appears for few of the promised ajax requests,

[image]

Also, inside Network tab of developer options I receive warning message:

> Provisional headers are shown

I don't know what I'm executing wrong here, or there is certain limitations to execute the multiple continuous ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your script fires several hundred or even thousends of ajax request simultaneously. I guess this is too much for your browser and maybe for the server too.
See here: [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse)

Try to reduce the number of parallel ajax-requests by merging them together.